# Trying to Use 'Angular Rails Templates' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, templates, slim-lang

so, I'm trying to use the templates folder in AngularJS instead of the 'views' folders that you'd normally use in Rails.

Things work great when I write everything in html, but what if I want to write things in slim, and still work with AngularJS templates, instead of rails Views?

The answer:  [angular rails templates](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates)

Unfortunately... it doesn't quite work.  It adds this at the beginning of my page before it successfully renders the rest from slim into html:

**Angular Rails Template // source: app/assets/templates/books/indexx.html.slim**

```
angular.module("templates").run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) { $templateCache.put("books/indexx.html", '

  //the rest of my webpage, beautifully rendered from slim to html****


') }]);
```

So it's close, but no cigar.  I've seen other work arounds for this, involving going into your config folder in rails and adding files and so on... but none of them seemed to work.  Any direction I should be looking here?  My main goal is just be able to use 'templates' in AngularJS (mainly so I can use the ui router) but be able to write them in SLIM instead of html.

EDIT:  Hmm... just restarted my server and now everything works. What's really scary is that everything works without the 'angular rails templates' gem... and also without any special config file in `config/initializers/angular_helper.rb` that looks like: # For Slim, remember also to add gem to Gemfile `Rails.application.assets.register_engine('.slim', Slim::Template)`

All I had to do was call the `filename.html.slim` in my `ui-router`...and everything works. RESTART THE SERVER I guess is the lesson

Sorry for wasting Stackoverflow space with this

Comment: Could we see your application.js file? The main one for your angular app.

Comment: Hmm... just restarted my server and now everything works.  What's really scary is that everything works without the 'angular rails templates' gem... and also without any special config file in config/initializers/angular_helper.rb  that looks like: # For Slim, remember also to add gem to Gemfile
Rails.application.assets.register_engine('.slim', Slim::Template)  All I had to do was call the filename.html.slim  in my ui-router...and everything works.  RESTART THE SERVER  I guess is the lesson

Comment: you have to be careful, it won't work in production because of the asset pipeline. The whole point of that gem is to have a consistent caching of the templates. Make sure you test that one out on a real server.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Angular Rails Template gem, you have to load your templates over

```
    templateURL: 'foo/bar/index.html'
```

when you path is app/assets/templates/foo/bar/index.html.