# Ng-scope issue with using angular-rails-template gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

So im using the angular rails template gem so that all of my views can be in angular, but im getting a weird error. This person before my had the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685764/trying-to-use-angular-rails-templates-gem), but they did not really solve it for me . And I have restarted my server three times, nothing changes or improves. Im hoping issue is just something small that I missed. Im hoping that if i give all the information i can someone can help me solve the problem. Thank you in advance for your help!

Here is the error.
[image]

This is what the code looks like in chrome dev tools.

```
 <html ng-app="planoxApp" class="ng-scope"><head><style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}</style>
  <title>PlanomaticPlanox2</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-dbbbca97c2bbaa173942d4281489e52f.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/static_pages-6d5d8811d0027e08fe46d86bf30c8766.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-2bb683376a024ac497c8a6ed6305cc12.css?body=1">
  <script src="/assets/jquery/dist/jquery-ba261596ffa80a71ab59381ea7dd96f4.js?body=1"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap-54b3f361138b446430a5c36b147ee6bd.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular/angular-bd1674de179777382eaa62905fa0241b.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-rails-templates-53580c7b4a0ee4550188e6540b876bbc.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-resource-911ad106aa18c275fb573b29b0d22827.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-route-ad9ba91d075e9c84eede0ae2bf206173.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular/app-75cf60e7081859d3351adaf0967a024c.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular/controllers/homectrl-439d28867cb055507c0c9a144dee04aa.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular/templates/home-1eff16fa2ee0622ee2aa2cf9d97ecc98.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular/routes-f0ee7156fd3678dae622e3321529f274.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/application-444cb0172e5f0e7601b6786933fa66df.js?body=1"></script>
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="DxpNe5E/1CUlu/XvBWpEy0VkCRqwFY+iIkgRWRwzBylyRxghD8iEOCRfj1SBj0OhqsUh5T/mwlMWW2ZQ9H4/ug==">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- ngView:  -->
<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
<span class="ng-scope">
// Angular Rails Template
    // source: app/assets/javascripts/angular/templates/home.html

    angular.module("templates").run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
      $templateCache.put("angular/templates/home.html", "</span><h1 class="ng-scope"> Help! </h1><span class="ng-scope">")
    }]);

    </span>
</div>


    </body></html>
```

And this is my app.js file

```
var planoxApp = angular.module('planoxApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'client-directives','templates']);
```

This is my route.js file

```
(function() {
    var planoxApp = angular.module('client-directives', []);

    planoxApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: "assets/angular/templates/home.html",
            controller: 'homectrl'
        }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }]);
})();
```

My application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require angular/angular
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require angular-resource
//= require angular-route
//= require angular/app
//= require_tree ./angular/controllers
//= require_tree ./angular/templates
//= require_tree .
```

This is my gem file.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use angular as the JavaScript library
gem 'bower-rails'
gem 'angular-rails-templates'
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~>0.8.0' #0.10.0 will be based on 0.8.x"
gem 'angular-ui-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'angularjs-rails'
gem 'sprockets', '2.12.3'


# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'rspec-rails'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

And finally this is my file structure for angular.

[image]

Edit: Forgot to add my home.html and Application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="planoxApp">
<head>
  <title>PlanomaticPlanox2</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-view>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Home.html

```
<h1> Help! </h1>
```

Comment: angular.module("templates") ... block should be inside script block.

Comment: Do you mind telling me/showing me where you are talking about? Script block?

Comment: @YoU is trying to tell you that you can't put script randomly in html without script tag. Don't seem to be bootstrapping angular anywhere either. Include all errors showing in browser console in your question also

Comment: There are no errors in my browser console. And im not calling any javascript outside of my application.html.erb, which i forgot to include so im going to add that. Literally the only thing I have in home.html is <h1> Help </h1> thats it.

Comment: So im trying to understand you correctly, i dont need apllication.html.erb then? Because angualr-rails-templates will handle it for me? So my home.html should look more like ....

`code`
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App!</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="planoxApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
      help
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
`code`